# SQL - Count how many time column occurs with two different values

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that I'm trying to determine the count of for a specific scenario:

```
Table [References]:
[County], [Vendor], [Status], [ID]
```

I need to know how many distinct [ID] values exist that contain a [Status] value of "FAILED" that do not also have a [Status] of "COMPLETED".  Basically, if there is a failed without a completed, i need the distinct amount for that.

Example:

```
County_1, Vendor_1, Failed, 12345.12
County_1, Vendor_1, Completed, 12345.12
County_1, Vendor_1, Failed, 12345.32
County_1, Vendor_1, Failed, 12345.32
County_1, Vendor_1, Failed, 12345.52
County_1, Vendor_1, Completed, 12345.52
County_1, Vendor_1, Failed, 12345.72
```

With this data, it should return a count of 2, since records 3 and 4 are failures that do not have a completed record and record 7 doesn't either.  It would be a distinct count so 3 and 4 would count as one since they are the same [ID]

Comment: Did you attempt an SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery for this. First extract all the distinct ID with 'failed' status then filter the ID that has a completed status. Please see bellow:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) 
FROM References 
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID 
    FROM References
    WHERE STATUS = 'COMPLETED'
)
AND STATUS ='FAILED'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Alex Glad i helped. Please accept as answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select id
  from refernce
  group by county, vendor, id
  having max(case when status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) != 
         max(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end)
  ) t
```

---

Here's a working example:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/202e4/1)

Comment: This answer looks correct to me.  I can't fathom why it would be downvoted.  (although I do prefer `<>` ;).

Comment: You cannot group by county. If you check the data 2 ID's can have the same county value. He wants the count of the distinct ID